# The reason for tagging of a non-OPTIONAL field in ASN.1

Tags: asn.1

Looking at an ASN.1 module for 3GPP MAP (http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/29_series/29.002/ASN.1/), I'm confused about the use of the `[0]` tag for the first field (imsi). Since it's not an OPTIONAL field, and its type is also known (OCTET STRING) what would be the purpose of the tag here?

```
sendAuthenticationInfo OPERATION  ::=  {
   ARGUMENT     SEQUENCE {
      imsi                                  [0] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING ( SIZE( 3 .. 8 ) ),
      numberOfRequestedVectors              INTEGER ( 1 .. 5 ),
      segmentationProhibited                NULL OPTIONAL,
      immediateResponsePreferred            [1] IMPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,

-- etc. --
```

One thing to note is that the imsi field is not directly interpreted as an octet string, but it holds the digits of an IMSI in semi-octet encoding (like BCD). Could that be the reason the field is tagged?

Comment: I do not see why field type may be important for its contents interpretation given the position of the field is known...

Comment: Could it have something to do with the global tagging mode (e.g. module-level, as set in the DEFINITION clause)?

Comment: I don't see any clauses in the module header. So I assume it should be the default.

Comment: The default is EXPLICIT so tagging this type implicitly kind of makes sense as an override. But it still does not explain why tagging is needed at all - why can't it be just a base OCTET STRING...? The other idea I can offer you is that this tagged field lets you add another optional base OCTET STRING field in front of the `imsi` field in the future.

Comment: This octet string is interpreted in a different way (semi-octets, encoding an IMSI like BCD). So maybe the intention was to tag it as being a different type.

Comment: I'm inclined to close this question as being opinion-based. We might just need someone who partook in the design of the original module to come up and tell the real motivation behind that [0] tag.

Comment: IMO you can still interpret it as semi-octets for as long as you can identify this field anyhow. You can identify it by its position in the data structure, by  field name in the schema as well as by some distinct tag.

Comment: I would keep this question. Not only someone more more knowledgeable may come up eventually, the question itself raises an interesting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the 3GPP MAP protocol specifies that BER is the encoding rule to be used, which means that tags are included in the encodings.  This means that while it is not strictly necessary in this case to change the default octet string tag for a non-optional field in this context since there is no ambiguity, it is likely done for documentation purposes, indicating that the contents of this field is not just an octet string.